# Why is my JupyterLab notebook code console not displaying 'command history' as it should?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

I am using an Jupyter Notebook (.ipynb) within JupyterLab and have created a new notebook console for the Jupyter Notebook by clicking on 'Create New Console for Notebook' in the File tab. However, I'm unable to view a 'command history' or a simultaneous display of the code cells I run in the Jupyter Notebook.

As mentioned in the documentation (https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/code_console.html), the code console can be used as a log of computations in that kernel.

What I know for sure is that the Jupyter Notebook and Code Console are definitely linked and are using the same kernel. However, I am unable to have the code console display a history of the code cells that I run in the Jupyter Notebook.

I have tried running code cells in the Jupyter Notebook by selecting Run->Run Selected Text or Current Line in Console. This procedure does display the code and output in the Console.

The documentation makes it seem that this should occur by default when the Jupyter Notebook and Code Console are linked. Hence my predicament.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have activate the option to show all kernel activity:

1. Click on the console tab (to activate)
2. Go to Commands
3. Under "Console" heading look for "Show All Kernel Activity" and click on it

Comment: Sweet! That makes it work. This feature however is not active by default. Do you know if I can make "Show All Kernel Activity" a default action each time I open a new console linked to the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Now you can edit the settings  in User Preferences under 'Settings' > 'Advanced Settings Editor' > 'Code Console' to `showAllKernelActivity": true`.